# How would graduate studies in Japan differ from those in the US, specifically for mathematics?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics, masters, japan

I have decided to make an academic transition from Electrical and Electronics Engineering into Mathematics after graduation. Although my first degree is from an Asian country it is a well accredited one. Japan is at the top of my list of countries where I wish to do my graduate-level studies. I'm particularly interested in doing a Master's program taught entirely in English and I see some National universities in Japan are conducting such courses under the G30 program (There might be other programmes as well).

But I have concerns regarding language being a barrier, as well as the rigour of the curriculum I will be studying there. My goal in the near future as of now is to get a good postdoc position.

In general, how would graduate studies in Japan differ from those in the US, specifically for mathematics?

Note: I've deleted my previous ambiguous question. Thank you @LoneAcademic for the suggested edits.

Comment: Where do you eventually hope to work? My observation is that studying in a country is most likely to open opportunities in or near that country.

Comment: @academic most likely to work in Japan. But would like to keep my options open in case I decide to work in the US. I'm more concerned about the rigour of the curriculum and the language barrier.

Comment: The admissions part of this question is addressed [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/176908/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-country-x/177170#177170)